# Sound in flash movie - can't get good sound quality after conversion

Tags: flash, audio, compression

I'm wondering why music videos on youtube sound high-grade (no distracting poor quality and artifacts), yet when I convert wave files recorded in an audio program, either to mp3 but mostly to ADPCM as that seems better, even when choosing the highest bit rate and 'best' for preprocessing, the audio files in the final swf sound noticeably degraded (not at all as smooth and comfy to the ears as  youtube sounds) and altered?

The files are short music files without vocals.

Is there some better method than the above compression methods (mp3, ADPCM, raw, etc) to convert wave files for swf export for use on the web, and get them as good as most on youtube and other online flash files with sound such as many games?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use an AAC codec. AAC is the norm for high quality lossy audio transcoding for media professionals. Have a look at this [article](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AACEncodingGuide). libfdk_aac is a great AAC codec (but there are some licensing issues depending on what you want to do with it).

AAC encoded content can be encapsulated in flash flv or f4v container and is commonly used on Youtube as of today.